# Macro Essbase Retrieval

Tags: excel, vba, essbase

I am trying to write a macro that will retrieve a selected range without having to press the "Retrieve" button under the Essbase Add-In tab. I am getting no where with all the VBA codes I have tried. My code is currently as follows:

```
Declare Function EssMenuVRetrieve Lib "ESSEXCLN.XLL" () As Long

Sub Update()

Sheets("Analysis").Select
Range("A1:C51").Select
X = EssMenuVRetrieve()

End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the error message:

"File not found: ESSEXCLN.XLL"

I ultimately want to use this code across multiple workbooks. Can anyone help me solve this issue.

Comment: 1) Are macros enabled? 2) Did you add the relevant Essbase function code?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12825_01/epm.111/esb_client/frameset.htm?idh_essmenuvretrieve.html

Comment: I updated my code above to what I am now trying. I now get "File not Found: ESSEXCLN.XLL

Comment: Do you have the essbase add-in loaded?

Comment: I see the Dodeca Essbase Add-In on the menu bar. Is there also an add-in I need to load for vba?

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if any changes need to made for the Dodeca add-in. More familiar with the old (buggy, deprecated) Essbase add-in.